# How to generate numbers within a range in a non random way with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math, colors, hsl

I know how to generate a random number between two numbers. But what I'd like to achieve is a way to generate a number between two numbers in a not totally random way. Let me explain...

So I have a function that generates a color based on a number passed into it. If that number is between 0 and 600, I'd like it to pass a number between 0 and 120 to the hue of the hsl value. If the number is greater than 600, I'd like a number between 120 and 240 passed to the hue of the hsl value. My function looks something like this:

```
getColor:function (number {
  var hue;
  var color;
  if (number <= 600) {
    hue = [A number between 0 and 120];
  } else if (number >= 600) {
    hue = [A number between 120 and 240];
  }
  color = 'hsl(' + hue + ', 100%, 80%)'
  return color;
 }
```

So the higher the number passed into the function, for example, between 0 and 600, the higher the hue value between 0 and 120. That make sense?

Thx u
-- Gaweyne

Comment: You say "I know how to generate a random number between two numbers"... so why not do that e.g. `hue = [A number between 0 and 120];` 0 and 120 are two numbers....

Comment: Ok let me elaborate.

I'd like the color that is generated when I pass in the number 60 to be a similar shade to the color generated when I pass in the number 70 but noticeably different. I'd also like for, say, if I passed the number 60 twice into the function, for the same color to be generated every time. Right now, I can pass in 60, and get a totally random value between 0 and 120, and pass 60 again, and get another totally random value.

This might sound a little confusing out of the context of my project. But does that make a little more sense?

Comment: So make a table mapping one number to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple Math:

```
hue = Math.floor(number * 120 / 600);
```

Or with both points:

```
function transpose(smin, smax, dmin, dmax) {
    var slen = smax - smin;
    var dlen = dmax - dmin;
    var ratio = dlen / slen;
    return function(num) {
      return num * ratio + smin;
    }
}

transpose(0, 600, 0, 120)(300); // 60
```

Comment: I failed math in school. Simple math is hard ;_;

Thx u. Forgot about Math.floor().

Comment: right, just skip `Math.floor` if you need float numbers.

Comment: Float numbers as opposed to integers, and rounding down with Math.floor might actually be preferable. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all you should know the maximum and minimum values of `number`. In my example The maximum value of number will be 1200 and the minimum 0, so the range is between 0 and 1200. And the range of `hue` is between 0 and 240.

the higher the `number` passed into the function, the higher the `hue` value.

0 `hue` = 0 `number`;

120 `hue` = 600 `number`;

240 `hue` = 1200 `number`;

=> 1 `hue` = (600 / 120) `number` = (1200 / 240) `number`

=> 1 `hue` = 5 `number`

In my example, (with `number` between 0 and 1200 and 600 is the middle) 1 value in `hue` is equal to 5 value in `number`. So :

```
hue = number / 5;
```

if you want hue to  be an integer just use `Math` :

```
hue = Math.floor(number / 5);
```

In my example `hue` will grow up by 1 every time you add 5 to `number`, it doesn't matter if `number` is less or more than 600 because the range of `number` on both sides of 600 is the same (600 is in the middle of the range). In case this is not what you want, and 600 is not in the middle of the range, you will have to do the same calculation above twice.

```
var max = [maximum value of number];
var min = [minimum value of number];

getColor:function (number {
   var hue;
   var color;
   if (number <= 600) {
      hue = Math.floor( number / ((600 - min) / 120) );
   } else if (number >= 600) {
      hue = Math.floor( number / ((max - 600) / 120) ) + 120;
   }
   color = 'hsl(' + hue + ', 100%, 80%)';
   return color;
}
```